# How do I programmatically make clicking on a UIImageView do something on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have programmatically added a UIImageView.  How do I make it send a message to my controller when the users clicks it, sending itself as the only parameter?

Answer (score 11):

I wouldn't use a UIImageView unless there was some other compelling reason.  I'd just use a custom UIButton and use the UIImage as its background.

Comment: I believe he wants specifically the UIImageView

Comment: I know, and I was recommending against that and proposing an alternative approach.

Answer (score 7):

1. Create a new class that extends UIImageView and use that.
2. In your class, override the touch events - touchesBegan, touchesEnded and/or touchesMoved as appropriate
3. From those methods, call back to a method on the controller.

Comment: You also have to set the userInteractionEnabled property to YES.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just put a custom button over the UIImage view, and use normally - buttons with Custom style are invisible and so will not obscure the image.  It's also a great way to turn regions of text into clickable areas as well.

Or, you could assign the custom image as a graphic background for the button.

Comment: Is there any way to leave it "invisible" (aka simply custom, without any background) but have it "darken" on click? Say, I have a custom View object overlayed by this one button and I want to give user feedback about him/her clicking on it.

Comment: You'd have to detect the button down action and affect the image somehow - or you could have a transparent black view over the image that you increase the alpha for on button down (you can have separate actions attached to "touch down" and "touch up inside").  But if you want to darken the image why not set that image as the custom button background and let it do the work for you?

Comment: Well there are some other objects on that image(labels), that I need to work with(set text etc...) But I want to make clickable the whole thing :)

Answer (score 2):

just put a button over the imageview, with the Alpha attribute set to 0.10 or less.
you can capture the button's tap event but almost cannot see it.

Comment: This is not a good solution. You can see it still. And you can't set the alpha to zero as it makes the button inactive. There are more elegant ways, for example just make it a custom button type and it will be invisible until you set a custom image.